# Is there consensus amongst climatologists that cold weather extremes are caused by global warming or human influence?

Tags: climate-change, climate, climatology, extreme-weather

Is there consensus amongst climatologists that cold weather extremes are caused by global warming or human influence?

I hear the claim a lot that the recent cold weather extremes (such as the polar vortex affecting the US) are caused by global warming, but haven't seen many scientific papers supporting it. I'm not sure if I just haven't come across more. And, I'm not sure if the ones that exist are even considered compelling by climatologists.

Comment: Your question seems US based. Please edit it and mention that you are talking about the US or add some date/sources pointing to other world regions as well. Also, the phrase "global warming or human influence" is a bit strange - it would imply that there are other men-made mechanisms *not* related to global warming. Is that really want you want to ask? (Take care not to make this a hidden second question arguing about global warming being man made or not).

Comment: By "global warming or human influence" I mean either caused by global warming or some other climate-change-related mechanism caused by men. Also, I'm not arguing that global warming isn't caused by man.

Answer (score 1):

It is common sense. The more energy in the Atmosphere the most intense will be the stirring up of it, so you will get cold polar air and hot tropical air moving around further and producing extreme weather.

Comment: Common sense, maybe, but this site needs answers with references.